# Deep linking into YouTube Upload from another iOS App

Tags: ios, swift, youtube

I make an app for video editing and would like to deep link from the save screen into places like YouTube and Instagram's upload screens.

Is there a way to deep-link into YouTube or YouTube Short's upload screen on the iOS app? I'm having trouble finding any deep-link URL schemes for YouTube (though I see Instagram does have some).

Answer (score 0):

No such deep-link exists for youtube.